# Can Java ant spawn a new terminal

Tags: java, ant

I have created a simple jar file, which contains the class I want to execute. And I use the following ant build target to execute it. I want to run my java class as a different process from ant.

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" spawn="true" classname="agents.QSteeringContinuous" >
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

What happens is that ant executes the java class in a different process but apparently somewhere on the background so I cant see the output from the class. Guys do you how can I make ant to spawn a new terminal window and execute my class inside this window?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `java` task to use `javaw` instead of `java`, so:

```
<java jvm="javaw.exe" ...>
```

I should caveat that I haven't tried this before (and I don't use ant anymore), but I don't see why this shouldn't work.